# PySpark 2.4.0: RDD map with split on lines from file random errors

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm trying to load in a DataFrame a set of vectors that I saved on a file with a textual format, for example:

```
2.846110820770263672e+00 -1.368924856185913086e+00 6.769183874130249023e-01
2.846110820770263672e+00 -1.368924856185913086e+00 6.769183874130249023e-01
```

...

I'm using  Spark 2.4.0 (built from sources) and my code is something like:

```
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName(appName).master("local[4]").getOrCreate()
data = sc.read.text(PATH_TO_VECTORS)
parsedData = data.rdd.map(lambda line: np.asarray([float(x) for x in line[0].split()]))
```

Sometime I obtain a float parse error on some randomic value that is not in the file itself.
For example, the first time the error could be "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '95e-01\x00\x001\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00..." and the second time it could be "could not convert string to float: '-1.436311483383178711e+00\x005e-01'" etc...

Does someone have an idea of what is going on? The weird thing is that each time I run my code I have a different value for which the float conversion is not working OR it works.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because spark uses `unicode` as *default encodings*. So some of the texts were read as \x00\x001\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 encoded strings. All you need to do is tell *spark* to read using *utf-8 encoding*. You should have it all set.

I would suggest you to use `sparkContext` to read the text file as there is a option to define the *encoding*. And you don't even have to convert to `rdd` as well as the data would be read as `rdds`. So you can do something like below

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf = conf.setAppName(appName).setMaster("local[4]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
data = sc.textFile(PATH_TO_VECTORS, use_unicode=False)
parsedData = data.map(lambda line: np.asarray([float(x) for x in line.split()]))
```

I hope the answer is helpful